# How to call backed API after getting first response from redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Following are my reducer into the redux side.
And I want to call one `axios` call after getting the response from the server side.

Here are two functions which contains the `getList` and `updateList`. So my requirement is when `updateListSuccess` response is get, I need to call function getDetails.

How to call `getDetails` function after getting the response which is denoted into the bold letter or asterisk.

```
 export function updateList(_id, data) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(updateListLoading());
    axios
      .put(`/api/dataList/${_id}`, data)
      .then(res => {
        **dispatch(updateListSuccess(res.data));**
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.response && err.response.data) {
          dispatch(updateListFail(err.response.data));
        }
      });
  };
}

export function getDetails() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getDetailsLoading());
    axios
      .get("/api/getDetails")
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(getSuccessResponse(res.data));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.response && err.response.data) {
          dispatch(getLoadfail(err.response.data));
        }
      });
  };
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok when you get success from first call just dispatch your other function 
You can do it as

```
 export function updateList(_id, data) {
 return dispatch => {
dispatch(updateListLoading());
axios
  .put(`/api/dataList/${_id}`, data)
  .then(res => {
    dispatch(updateListSuccess(res.data));
      dispatch(getDetails())
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.response && err.response.data) {
      dispatch(updateListFail(err.response.data));
    }
  });
  };
 }
```

Hope it helps